# Is ObjectBox DB compatible across languages and platforms?

Tags: objectbox

I built and ran a DB in Java on Android.  Now I would like to migrate my app to Dart/Flutter.  So a couple questions:

1. Will the models I create in Dart be compatible with the ones I have in Java?
2. Assuming yes for question 1, will the Dart app be able to use the same copy of DB file created in Java?
3. Will the Dart app be able to use the same copy of the DB file across systems (Android, iOS, and Linux)?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, in general this should be possible. There may be subtle differences caused by Dart types (e.g. Java has many integer types), or even by ObjectBox's Dart implementation. That latter should be reported to ObjectBox issues though, as Sync would run into the same issue.
2. Yes (assuming no issues in 1 were encountered)
3. Yes, this might work although no guarantees are given. This is outside of internally tested use cases.

Comment: Hi @Markus Junginger, I migrated all my Java models to Dart and ensured the types match (for instance for Java int types, I added annotation   @Property(type: PropertyType.int)).  The simple app runs on Linux when accessing the DB files created by it.  But when I copied my "data.mdb" from the Java app on Android into Linux, the app crashes with obscure flutter error messages of some methods not available.  I even copied the json model file from Java.  The crash has to do with Store(getObjectBoxModel()).  Any advice on what to do?

Comment: Stepping through debug, the crash actually occur at line     _cStore = C.store_open(opt); in Store.dart.

Comment: See https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/issues if you can find your issue there. If not, please create a new one with details of your crash.